# Operators *+/- don't work with my variable created using a for () loop

Tags: php, for-loop

I created a form dropdown using the 'for' loop listed below.

```
<?php
for ( $i=3; $i<6; $i += .01 ) {
echo '<option value="'.money_format('$%i', $i) .'">'.money_format('$%i', $i) .'</option>';
}
?>
```

variable was created using the POST method

```
$cost = $_POST["cost"];
```

When I echo the variable, I can see the correct value, but when I try to perform a calculation using an operator (*/-+) the value is echoed as a 0.

```
$total_cost = $cost * 10;
```

Any ideas?

Thank you!

Todd

Comment: Because `$_POST['cost']` begins with a dollar sign, so it's not a valid number for PHP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take the dollar sign out of the option value:

```
echo '<option value="'.money_format('%i', $i) .'">'.money_format('$%i', $i) .'</option>';
```

Comment: Barnar, THANK you for your help! They was the solution I was looking for. Have a great day!